# Where is FacebookAds\Object\AdAccount::getReportsStats() in Facebook Ads SDK 2.4.0?

Tags: php, facebook, facebook-ads-api

I just updated Facebook Ads SDK from 2.3.1 to 2.4.0. I'm getting an error:

> Fatal error: Call to undefined method
>   FacebookAds\Object\AdAccount::getReportsStats()

I took a look at the source and this is true, `getReportsStats()` method is gone. It used to be [here](https://github.com/facebook/facebook-php-ads-sdk/blob/2.3.1/src/FacebookAds/Object/AdAccount.php#L298-L302), but [is not anymore](https://github.com/facebook/facebook-php-ads-sdk/blob/2.4.0/src/FacebookAds/Object/AdAccount.php).

What is the replacement in the newest Facebook Ads SDK for PHP?

Answer (score 1):

Try asking in the github for that SDK for further info on changes made to the the SDK itself, though the API docs use examples from that SDK as well as the actual API examples and appears to be primarily via `->getInsights()` calls on a campaign, ad set, etc

The API itself has documented changes between v2.4 (current version) and v2.3 (deprecated, scheduled for removal in October 2015) in how reports are fetched - only the [/insights](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/marketing-api/insights/v2.4) edge on an account, campaign is supported in v2.4:

https://developers.facebook.com/docs/marketing-api/changelog#v2_4_changes

Comment: Exactly, I ended up using `getInsights()` method :)